# Will a non-dimmable LED work if the dimmer switch is on full?

Tags: lighting, led, bulb

If a dimmer switch is fitted for the room but we get non-dimmable LED lamps (GU10), I know there may be flickering problems with dimming, but will they work fine if the dimmer is turned to max?

Comment: Probably, but I would be concerned that the dimmer could be accidentally turned down, damaging the lamp. It'd be worth putting in a simple $2 switch to protect a $20 lamp.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, LED bulbs typically work fine on dimmers set to max.  In my experience, even the "non-dimmable" ones don't seem to be harmed when dimmed although your mileage here may vary with bulb and dimmer models.

This seems to be a big improvement in comparison with "non-dimmable" CFLs, which seem to be very susceptible to destruction - I have destroyed several after just seconds of dimming.